# How can I embed a mailitem into a word document as a msg file

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

I have a word document with a table in it, it is a log for Emails. Column 1 is the date of the Email, column 2 is the subject line, and in column 3 I would like to embed the actual Email so it shows as a MSG file. 
This VBA is in the word document, and I have opened the mail item from vba in word.

How do I embed the mail item?

```
Sub create_log()
Dim appOL As Outlook.Application
Dim appFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim nsOL As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
Dim items As Outlook.items
Set appOL = New Outlook.Application
Set nsOL = appOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set appFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Email_log")

Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim cell As Word.cell
Dim row As Long
Dim rows_needed As Long

Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument

If doc.Tables.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Too many tables, there should only be one"
    Exit Sub
End If
Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
rows_needed = appFolder.items.Count - tbl.Rows.Count
While rows_needed > 0
    tbl.Rows.Add
    rows_needed = rows_needed - 1
Wend
Set items = appFolder.items
items.Sort "ReceivedTime", False
row = 2
For Each mailItem In items
    tbl.cell(row, 1).Range.Text = Left(mailItem.ReceivedTime, 12)
    tbl.cell(row, 2).Range.Text = mailItem.Subject
    tbl.cell(row, 3).Range.  ***how do I add mailItem*** 

    row = row + 1
Next mailItem

End Sub
```

This is what I want the end result to look like. Note the word document and table are already existing, the macro just fills in the cells in the table.
[image]

Comment: Can you add an image example to what your word doc should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Save the email to a .msg file, then pass the path to that file in the [Range.InsertFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835231.aspx) method.

Comment: I tried the Range.InsertFile but ended up with binary text filing the word document. 'tbl.cell(row, 3).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject olMSG, fileName, False, True, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1033\OUTLLIBR.DLL", 35, subject' seems to work, but now the ICON reference is hard coded.

Comment: You could get the path to that .dll through other means so it isn't hardcoded. What parameters did you use for InsertFile?

Comment: Saving as a MSG file and then inserting did work. However I used the AddOLEObject instead of insertFile method.  the parameters that I used to insert the icon was  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1033\OUTLLIBR.DLL", 35, which is the path the outlook exe file and 35 was the index of the icon, I just iterated through the values until I fount the icon I wanted.